# Removing "offline available" cached files

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, offline-files

I made the mistake on actually enabling this feature on one of my network drives in Windows 7.

It's insanely annoying because it seems as it doesn't even make a real attempt to connect to the online version when there IS an internet connection.

For example: All my other network drives are available, only +/- 5 minutes later will my cached drive be the real, online network drive.

So I decided to disable the function again. But for some reason: those cached files are still there! And this still happens every time.

Does anyone know how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into 'Sync Center' > Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Sync Center

Then click 'Manage Offline files' (left hand menu), there are many options in there regarding your 'Offline Files' (ie network files copied to your local machine by Sync Center) including removing them (and disabling Offline files).

*Sidenote - Anyone noticed how the americanisation of Centre has now taken over everything? Even online any references to 'Centre' generally redirect to 'Center', my windows locale is set to 'English (British)' yet programs like Sync Center remain named incorrectly.*

Comment: "Centre" is French, not English.  The English word is "center". "Spelling with *-re* popularized in Britain by Johnson's dictionary (following Bailey's), though *-er* is older and was used by Shakespeare, Milton, and Pope."  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=center