# Remove Computer from Sync Center Offline Files Folder

Tags: windows-7, sync-center

I had enabled offline file sync for a network share. I have since deleted the offline copy, by essentially doing what's described [here](https://superuser.com/a/364758). However, the computer still shows up under **Offline Files Folder** > **Computers**, even after reboot. It's the only computer listed. There are currently no files available for offline access. How can that computer be removed from the list?

Comment: [have you tried this](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-disable-sync-center-offline-files-windows-7)

Comment: That's to disable Offline Files completely, which isn't what I want to do. I want to keep Offline Files enabled, I just want the computer removed from the list, since I'm no longer synchronizing files with it. But yes, I did disable it, reboot, and then re-enable it, and the computer is still listed.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure all your files are synchronized. Then I recommend you doing the following:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942974
> To resolve this problem, re-initialize the cache of offline files. To do this, >follow these steps:
> Click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press Enter.
>
> Note If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type the password or click Continue.
> Locate the following registry subkey, and then right-click it:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CSC
> Point to New, and then click Key.
> Type Parameters in the box.
> Right-click Parameters, point to New, and then click DWORD (32-bit)Value.
> Type FormatDatabase, and then press Enter.
> Right-click FormatDatabase, and then click Modify.
> In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
> Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

This will wipe your Offline Files partnership towards the old server and you can re-establish a partnership towards the new one.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.